# ASP .NET 4.7 MVC Authentication and Authorization Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, asp.net-web-api

I am creating a MVC web API. The endpoints will be hidden behind authentication via a custom token. However, there will also be scoping on certain individual endpoints, access to admins etc. I am trying to figure out how to create a user, or, when the user is authenticated to set him so in the authorization filter I can verify if he is an admin, or if he has read access to that particular resource at that endpoint.

What is the best way to do this, can I set the identity principal in the authentication filter, or is there a better way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can used the [Authorize] Attribute my friend ,

**first :** add the AuthorizeAttribute filter to the global filter list:

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
    }
```

**second :** to secure your controller ,add the filter as an attribute to the controller

```
// Require authorization for all actions on the controller.
[Authorize]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id) { ... }
    public HttpResponseMessage Post() { ... }
}
```

**three** to secure your action , add the attribute to the action method:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get() { ... }

    // Require authorization for a specific action.
    [Authorize]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post() { ... }
}
```

i advise you to visit this 2 link can help you more:

[Authentication and Authorization in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api)
[MVC Web API: Authorization & Authentication](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/013102/mvc-web-api-authorization-authentication/)